# format value in loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, pug

I wanted to format a value for all the loop, but only the first one is formated:

```
each value in values
   span#amount #{amount}

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/accounting.js/0.3.2/accounting.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(function () {   
        function money(value) {
            return accounting.formatMoney(value, "$");
         }

         $("#amount").each(function(){
    var val = $(this).text();
    $(this).text(money(val));
});
```

How can I do it?

Comment: IDs must be unique. The issue has absolutely nothing to do with node.js, express nor jade.

Comment: Ok, I use class, it is working now.